# Can't find downloaded file on device

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm writing an application to download a file from a URL at the click of a button. The problem is that after the (apparently) successful download, I can't find the file in my SD card. I've even tried to output the `Context.fileList()` String array, but it contains nothing (resulting in the error Log "No files created").

How can I say the download was performed at all? Well, I see the data connection get active as soon as the button is pressed, and it relaxes only after 3-4 seconds, during which I assume it was downloading the less-than-100KB file.

Here's the code for main Activity:

```
package com.filedownloaddemo;

import java.io.File;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    // URL to download from
    String url = "http://www.edco.ie/_fileupload/The%20Interlopers%20-%20A%20short%20story%20by%20Saki.pdf";
    // file variable
    File outputFile;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // set Android policy
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    // onClick handler for the button
    public void download(View v) {
        try {
            outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myfile.pdf");
            DownloadHelper.downloadFile(url, outputFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DL_Error", e.getMessage());
        }

        if (this.fileList().length == 0) {
            Log.d("DL_Error", "No files created.");
        } else {
            // write file names to Log
            for (String s : this.fileList()) {
                Log.d("Download", s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the file that downloads (this is taken from one of the answers on this community):

```
package com.filedownloaddemo;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.util.Log;

public class DownloadHelper {

    public static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
            int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

            DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
            stream.readFully(buffer);
            stream.close();

            DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    outputFile));
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DL_Error", e.getMessage()); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Where is your file name??? You should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/filename.pdf";

Comment: "Swallowing" exceptions is bad, `Log` them (don't use `printStackTrace()` on Android)

Comment: How are you checking for the existence of this file?

Comment: @BharatJyoti File name is in `outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Comment: @KenWolf See the `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called at all, this is not a good place to check :)

Comment: @KenWolf Oops! Thanks for that. I'll set it elsewhere and also catch the formerly swallowed exceptions. Back in a while.

Comment: @dotslash Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the path to the SDcard not the filename. It will return /mnt/sdcard, thats it. You debug for sometimes you will come to know

Comment: @BharatJyoti Yeah . . . I'm getting the error: "/mnt/sdcard: open failed: EISDIR is a directory."

Comment: Exactly, first thing you check whether u have added the uses-permision in the menifest file. It should be android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. And also you should not download file in the main thread. Use AsynTask. U will get error on 4.0+ devices

Comment: I do have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but this AsynTask thing is new to me. Will read up on it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

is not the right place to save a file, you need to give it a filename.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myfile.pdf";
```

Also make sure you have the following permission in your `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to get called so this is not a good place to check.

Finally, to see the file when you connect your device to your pc you might need to let `MediaScanner` know that there's a new file to index.

Send a broadcast once the file has been saved to ensure it gets picked up in the `MediaStore`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Well, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myfile.pdf";` is throwing an error because the former is of type File. What is the correct way?

Comment: `outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myfile.pdf");`

Comment: Please see edited original post. Now getting `No files created` error.

Comment: `Context.FileList` is not the right way to check. Use  `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myfile.pdf"); if (file.exists()) ...` to check. `Context.Filelist` is only for private, internal files saved to internal storage. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList()

Comment: Excellent! I just changed this and the file is being downloaded smoothly. Phew, I can't believe this has finally yielded . . . Thank you so very much for your time! :)